# Returning the same type as called with when inheriting overrided operators

Tags: python, inheritance, methods

Imagine this situation in Python:

```py
class A:
    def __init__(self, v):
        self.val = v

    def __add__(self, b):
        return A(self.val + b.val)

class B(A):
    def __init__(self, v):
        super().__init__(v)
```

It's clear that B inherits the `__add__` operator override from its parent, A.

If I have some instances of these objects, and perform some addition:

```py
foo = A(3)
bar = B(4)
baz = B(5)

alp = foo + foo
bet = foo + bar
gam = bar + baz
```

`alp` has the type `A`, which is expected. `bet` also does, which is maybe less expected, but not surprising.

`gam` has type `A`, however, which is irritating, because we've added two instances of `B` to get it.

My question is: how can this be done so that `gam` has type `B`? Does it require overriding each operator (e.g. `__add__`) on B explicitly to cast the result of `super().__add__(b)` to the type of B? Or is there a smarter, cleaner way of getting this to work?

Thank you.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

instead of calling `A(...)` call `type(self)(...)`. The `type(self)` will return the class of the current object.